# Brute force in Matlab

Tags: matlab

this is my problem, for example i have an equation x + y =2, so using matlab i want to know how to determine all the possible combination of values of x and y when you add it, and will give sum of 2 (ex: x1 = 0.98, y1 =0.12; x2=0.94 y2=0.16, and etc)

i think i need to use for loop?

```
for x = 2-y
end
for y =2-x
end

Values of x and y
x   y
0   2
0.1 1.9
0.2 1.8
0.3 1.7
0.4 1.6
0.5 1.5
0.6 1.4
0.7 1.3
0.8 1.2
0.9 1.1
1   1
```

so guys i need your help thanks

Comment: The set of all values where `x + y = 2` is infinite.  Do you want to restrict the range of `x` and `y` to something sensible?

Comment: yes, i think just like in my example, from x=0/y=0 to x=2/y=2, disregard those negatives and the interval is 0.1

Answer (score 2):

To get all possible combinations of `x` and `y` between `0` and `2` with a step size of `0.1` you don't even need a for loop. You can create a vector `x` which contains all possible `x` values and then calculate the corresponding `y`'s:

```
x = 0:0.1:2;    % Create a vector of values between 0 and 2 in steps 0f 0.1
y = 2 - x;
```

This will give you two (row) vectors containing all possible combinations which add up to `2`.